# Who is this Ant Woman character in this image alongside the Wasp?

Tags: marvel, character-identification

I came across this image, it looks to be Wasp and a female version of Ant Man in some kind of Fantastic Voyage type adventure?

I haven't been able to find anything regarding Ant-Woman/Girl/Lady when trying to look up who this could be.

[image: A shrunken Wasp alongside a shrunken female character to be indentified]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## [Laura Kinney aka X-23](https://www.marvel.com/characters/x-23)

The image has been taken from [*All-New Wolverine (2015) #5*](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/56436/all-new_wolverine_2015_5), [ComicsVerse](https://comicsverse.com/new-wolverine-5-review-honey-shrunk-wolverine/) has the following description of the issue:

> The Wasp and the All-New Wolverine, wearing Ant-Man suits, inside of the body of Zelda…?
>
> Tom Taylor’s first story arc about the All-New Wolverine draws to a close as Laura Kinney has to steal an Ant-Man suit in order to fight for her clone’s/friend’s life—inside of that clone’s body! Obviously, the current owner of Pym Enterprises—Janet van Dyne, a.k.a. The Wasp—is not too happy about that. Meanwhile, Alchemaxx Industries has found the traces the three sisters have left behind, and they plan on solving this problem once and for all.

Below is the appropriate page showing the panel:

[image: All-New Wolverine (2015) #5 showing the source image]

Comment: FWIW I found this by reverse image searching.

Comment: I know I'm meant to wait before accepting an answer, but that's obviously the one (and thanks for explaining how you found it, will bear that in mind)

Comment: @Brian Accepting an answer and when is entirely the prerogative of the OP, you don't need to wait at all if you don't want to. And FWIW some types of questions it makes more sense to wait before accepting and some it doesn't.